# Posting datas from one asp.net page to another when click a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 ASP.Net WebForm named as webform1.aspx,webform2.aspx.
Webform1.aspx contain Register area with textboxes for name,address,age etc to register Student Profiles.
Webform2.aspx contain a messge area to ensure that the Registred student is valid.

I have a Submitt Button in webform1.aspx. Upon clicking, it will post the Register datas to Message area of Webform2.aspx &If Valid it post to database. 
So, how can I do it for get the details from one form to another?
I want code in C#.net.

Comment: Why do you use different pages for this? You could use  `UserControls` which you make visible/invisible.

Comment: From the sound of it, this is a school/college assignment. I suggests you take a peek at the Request object.

Comment: If you use `Server.Tansfer` you can access all properties and controls of the `PreviousPage` property.

Answer (score 0):

Having 2 aspx pages to do this simple registration task is not really how you should go about ASP.net programming.

The standard ASP.net way of doing this would be: 
Start with one page aspx which has:

- the name, address, password inputs
- a submit button
- a message area

Set the message area to be invisible (in the IDE right click it and select Properties).

Add an onclick function to the submit button (in the IDE double-click on the button) and in that function put all the validation code, and code to make the name, address, password and submit inputs invisible and make the message area visible.